# After Express App is initialized, I can't add objects to module.exports

Tags: node.js, express, meanjs

server.js

```
module.exports.a = 'abc';
var app = expressAppConstructor(db);
module.exports.b = 'xyz';
console.log(JSON.stringify(module.exports)); // --> {"a":"abc","b":"xyz"}
```

exportsLog.js

```
var io = require('./server');
console.log(JSON.stringify(io)); // --> {"a":"abc"} Note b: xyz is missing
```

**How can I add `b` to `module.exports` after the Express App is initialized?**

I'm on the [mean.js](https://github.com/meanjs/mean) Stack and the mentioned files above are `server.js`, `expressConstructorFunction` is `require(./config/express.js)`

See original contents of [server.js](https://github.com/meanjs/mean/blob/master/server.js), [config/express.js](https://github.com/meanjs/mean/blob/master/config/express.js)

Comment: Are you getting an error at all? I would suspect that `expressAppContstructor` must be throwing an error if the second call is being ignored. Does a `console.log` run after the app initialization?

Comment: I am not getting any errors.

Comment: Nothing changes when using `exports` instead of `module.exports`

Comment: that's why I linked the [file](https://github.com/meanjs/mean/blob/master/config/express.js) ;-)

Comment: I deleted that line. This is my [current version](http://pastebin.com/hAznY7Dc)

Comment: If your whole app is public and hosted on Github or something, I'd be happy to clone it and run it locally to help debug.

Comment: I will happily add you to the private Gitlab repo if you email me at clksdebugging@mailinator.com

Comment: I think you are confusing [Gitlab](https://gitlab.com) for Github. There is no user named chevex on gitlab.

Comment: Yep, read it as "github". You should have an email :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After debugging with your actual app I've discovered the reason the second setting doesn't work. It does work, but when you initialize your express app you are requiring the server file in one of your routes.

`node server.js` -> `exports.a = 'abc';` -> `expressAppConstructor` ->

```
config.getGlobbedFiles('./app/routes/**/*.js').forEach(function(routePath) {
  require(path.resolve(routePath))(app);
});
```

-> in one route file loaded via the above, this runs: `require('server.js');` -> now finally the stack returns to the server file and does: `exports.b='xyz';`, but the module has already been required and cached by your route file.

I would actually be worried that you're starting the server over and over each time you require the file. Though I think it's not breaking because node caches modules that have been required so the logic isn't running, but the `exports` on the cached server module only has the first assignment since it was required by your route file before the second assignment to `exports` even occurs. By the time your route file tries to load the server file, it has only run up to the app initialization line. Anything added to `exports` after you've required it in your route file obviously isn't going to make it onto the exported data.